# python if test == (name or surname) vs if (name or surname ) in test

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I would like someone to explain me why one works and the other not:

```
>>> test
'test1'
>>> name 
'test'
>>> surname
'test1'
>>> is_good = "good" if (name or surname) in test else "bad"
>>> is_good
'good'
>>> is_good = "good" if test == (name or surname) else "bad"
>>> is_good
'bad'
```

for me it is quite the same although I do not understand what happens in the background of the operations.

second it would be great to have such functionality in python to not to repeat test == name or test == surname ...

third is there a PEP which says anything about that ?

Answer (score 2):

logical operators are evaluated in left to right order. For ex,

```
>>> 'test' or 'test1'
'test'
>>> 'test1' or 'test'
'test1'
```

You could see that,if first  operand is non-zero,then python simply output first operand and does not care about what comes after `or`. This could be seen above as 'test' returned.

In your case,

```
 is_good = "good" if (name or surname) in test else "bad"
```

or returns 'test' which is verified by `in` surname which is `True`

In your second case,

```
 is_good = "good" if test == (name or surname) else "bad"
```

which in turn converted as

```
 is_good = "good" if 'test1' == 'test' else "bad"
```

which turn to be `False`

Comment: +1, although 'non-zero' is quite right (especially for strings), despite the name of the relevant magic method in Python 2. `''` is treated as False, for example, even though `'' == 0` is also False. The usual catch all terms are "truthy" and "falsey", for `bool(x)` being True or False respectively. Strings follow the convention that sequences are falsey if and only if they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers correctly explain what `or` is doing (it checks that either one of the names is really there an not 0, "", null etc.).  I think you are looking for something like

```
if test in {name,surname}
```

This constructs a set and checks for membership.  A tuple `test in (name,surname)` might be more efficient.  But really, there is nothing wrong with `(test == name) or (test == surname)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a fun question !
Lets look at 'or' and 'and' function a little bit. 
both functions do not return True or False, but return the last relevant object. 'or' returns the first True object (since after finding it, the function knows it is true), and 'and' returns the first False object (since after finding it, the function knows it is false).
For example:

```
>>> False or 2 or 3 or 4
2
>>> True and [1] and "" and 123
""
```

Python treats an empty string ("") as False and a positive number (2) as True. Inserting these values into an "if" statement would run a bool() type function on the returned value of the "and" and "or" functions.

so when you run :

```
"good" if (name or surname) in test else "bad"
```

You are actually asking if name ("test") is in test ("test1"). (name or surname) returns name since it is not an empty string. Python checks if it can find this substring inside the test string, and it can, so it returns True.

But running:

```
"good" if test == (name or surname) else "bad"
```

Is like asking if test ("test1") is equal to name ("test").

The right way of writing it is:

```
"good" if test in (name,surname) else "bad"
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests:

```
>>> test = 'test1'
>>> name = 'test'
>>> surname = 'test1'
>>> name or surname
'test'
>>> name or test
'test'
>>> '1234' or '6543'
'1234'
>>> (name or surname) in test
True #however this does not mean what you think it means
>>> ('1' or '2') in '234'
False #even though you'd expect True
>>> '1' or '2'
'1'
>>> '2' or '1'
'2'
```

As you can see, when you do `string` or `string`, it simply returns the first string.

Therefore, what you want is something like:

```
>>> (name in test) or (surname in test)
True
```

OR

```
>>> test in (name,surname)
True
```

Hope that clarified some peculiar things about `python` and `strings` and `comparisons`

Comment: `test in name + surname` is dangerous.  `("cat"  in  "doc" + "attack") == True`.  And you don't want that.